# #php - "page expire" instead of "session expire"

Tags: php, session

After my search in stackoverflow, I learn how to use session to expire. Thanks stackoverflow!

The code is:

```
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
$login_session =check_username($user_check);
if(!isset($login_session)){
header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 600)) {
// last request was more than 10 minutes ago
session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
echo "<script>alert('Time-out(10 minutes) - Please log-in again.');location.reload();</script>";
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

My question is:

If I open two webpage tab at the same time (e.g. page A and page B), I keep doing some activities on page B but not on page A, how can I expire page A after 10 mins while I continue to work on page B by using the same session? Please help, many thanks!!

Comment: After Page A expires what should that page do ? redirect to active page or what ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Redirect to homepage (index.php)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Page Expire" do you want the user to login again after certain time of inactivity on one tab/window of same browser while they're working on other from same website? I don't think that'd be possible.

But if you just want to detect if they've been idle for certain amount of time and then do some activity, like redirecting them to some other page.. or show an alert or any such thing.. that can be done via **JavaScript/jQuery NOT PHP**.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
Yes, I want to redirect to homepage and ask the user to login again.